# How to prevent back button from killing the textview details

Tags: android

i'm developing a basic app that has four activities. The first two Activities have textviews that are reseted when the back button is pressed. here's the manifest

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ContactActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Page2Activity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
        <activity android:name=".FinalActivity"></activity>
```

I've also used the android:freezesText="true" but it doesnt help

Answer (score 1):

I didnt write any android programs. But you should try android:alwaysRetainTaskState:"false"
Whether or not the state of the task that the activity is in will always be maintained by the system — " true " if it will be, and " false " if the system is allowed to reset the task to its initial state in certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution may be saving the data in string form and repopulating your object on resume. You would save the data in onPause() and repopulate in onResume().
I will show you how to do that with a SharedPreference. SharedPreferences are an easy way to save strings, integers, lists, and other objects, without a database in android.

```
//This code will save a string. The first parameter in putString() is the key. The second is the value
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("myTextviewText", "Hello World");        
//Save the data
editor.apply();

//This code will retrieve the String. You can run this code and retrieve the value even if the app was killed

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("myTextViewText", "default");
```

You can override onPause and in there use the first part of the code to save what you want in your textview. I'm onResume use the second part to retrieve the string and then edit the textview text with the restored text. To hold serveral values just use a different key to set and get data.

SharedPreferences will save when the app is stopped. They act like a database but with less maintenance.